# How to make fixed-width pages zoomed-out on mobile?

Tags: html, css, width, fixed

I have a bunch of landing pages that are fixed-width.  All of them appear very zoomed-in on mobile browsers.

What I have done:

- I removed the `meta` `viewport` tag all together.  No changes.
- I set the width at several various sizes, for example `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">`, but this did nothing, though I was certain it would work.
- Several more variations of the `viewport` tag.

I'm at a loss. Ideally, I'd just make all these landing pages responsive, but I have at least 20 of them and just want them to look decent for now.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Add this to your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    html {zoom:0.8;}
}
```

Manipilate the zoom untill you get it right.

Comment: I've tried a bunch.  That one you provided didn't work as well.  :(

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Removing the viewport actually worked on my iphone it just wasn't showing on an iphone simulator I was using.  Thanks for the help!!!